# Exception: Unable to locate gradlew script. Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

[image: Exception: Unable to locate gradlew script.]
This is the error that I am getting, I have tried reinstalling the android sdk, Can someone suggest a solution for this?
Thanks in advance..

**Edit:**
After getting the error I tried cleaning the project and also ran flutter doctor. There I got the issue which was
[image: Flutter doctor output]

So I also ran flutter doctor --android-licenses, where I got the error
[image: Android licenses error]

Answer (score 0):

See if the fapp/android/gradlew.bat exists or there may be issues with the internet connection which failed to download gradel.
Try creating another Flutter Project with a reliable internet connection.
If there is still problem then try `flutter doctor` see if there are any errors or Do `flutter clean` in your project directory and then run your project.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok. So I tried everything from the internet..downgraded the android version too..But nothing helped..I am posting the issue on Android Studio github page..Might find some solution there atleast